# Long setTimeout on NodeJs gets ignored by event queue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a long-running nodejs (v.10.16) application that occasionally needs to schedule an event to fire one to two months in the future. Unfortunately, this exceeds the maximum length of time that a timeout can wait. I have tried using various different packages (long-timeout) but they didn't seem to work for me.

Essentially, the code I've settled on looks something like the below

```
function runInFuture(millisecondsInFuture,callback) {
    if(millisecondsInFuture > MAX_TIMEOUT) { // max timeout === 2^31-1 https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args
        setTimeout(()=>{
            runInFuture(millisecondsInFuture - MAX_TIMEOUT,callback); //for simplicity, code to ensure no errors from floating point numbers excluded
        },MAX_TIMEOUT - 1);
     } else {  // timing is within setTimeout's ability to run 
        setTimeout(()=>{
            callback();
        },millisecondsInFuture);
     }
}
```

From what I understand, the above function should keep calling itself recursively every ~24.86 days until the event is expected to happen in less than that time, after which it will fire the callback. In actual practice, the callback doesn't get fired. Is there any setting on nodejs I'm not following? Any tips on where to locate the bug? Or, is it possible to somehow 'speed up' the system clock so I don't have to wait 25 days to find out that my code isn't working?

Comment: *is it possible to somehow 'speed up'* If you use unit tests for it, you can try to use `jasmine.clock`. You can pass manual tick and execute a future event instantaneously.

Comment: Just execute the `setTimeout` every day (week) and check the date if you have to trigger the event.

Comment: @Rajesh seems like `jasmine.clock` overrides the standard setTimeout, so whatever results I get won't be comparable

Comment: @Andreas thanks, it seems less elegant but firing 4-8 times reliably vs. firing once unreliably makes sense

Comment: @serakfalcon you see, it has a method called tick where you can specify the ticks and it jumps to that time instantaneously. So you can test long timeout without a delay

Comment: @Rajesh thanks I understand that, but it won't actually test the standard implementation of setTimeout, it tests a implementation built by jasmine.

Comment: @serakfalcon you would be testing your logic. setTimeout be it of js or Jasmine are standard functions that work. The whole point of unit testing is given no side effect, your logic works

Comment: @Rajesh yah my problem is logic works, but there is side effect :D

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you tried a few libraries, but [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) seems like it would serve your purposes well. As you are aware `setTimeout` has a 32 bit limit of just under 25 days, and is vulnerable to system failure due to only being stored in memory. It is possible to restore from a reference to an Agenda schedule upon server restart if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We've implemented our own scheduler that has a number of features Agenda doesn't support, so unfortunately that won't work for this case.